# Waiting for ExecuteAsync() result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I have the following problem with my RestSharp implementation. How can I get my application to wait for the response from `ExecuteAsync()` before continuing?

I tried different solutions:

First (the method doesn't wait for the ExecuteAsync response):

```
public Task<Connection> Connect(string userId, string password)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl)
            {
                Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("user", userId,
                    "password", password)
            };
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Connection>();
        var request = new RestRequest(AppResources.Authenticating);
        client.ExecuteAsync<Connection>(request, response =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(new JsonDeserializer().
                     Deserialize<Connection>(response));
            });
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

So I tried this, but the application freezes :

```
   public Task<Connection> Connect(string userId, string password)
    {
        EventWaitHandle executedCallBack = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl)
            {
                Authenticator = new SimpleAuthenticator("user", userId, 
                     "password", password)
            };
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Connection>();
        var request = new RestRequest(AppResources.Authenticating);
        client.ExecuteAsync<Connection>(request, response =>
            {
                tcs.SetResult(new JsonDeserializer().
                          Deserialize<Connection>(response));
                executedCallBack.Set();
                });
        executedCallBack.WaitOne();
        return tcs.Task;
    }
```

Comment: It comes from `RestSharp` library, a kind of `WebClient`

Comment: what's Connection ? I can't find this class in RestSharp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing the point of Task and the async/await pattern.

You don't wait inside this method, but because you are returning a `Task<>` it allows a caller to wait for it asynchronously it if chooses.

A caller would be something like this:

```
 public async void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
 {
     Connection result = await restClient.Connect(this.UserId.Text, this.Password.Text);

      //... do something with result
 }
```

The compiler knows how to make this code, which is very similar to the synchronous (blocking) equivalent, and turn it into asynchronous code.

Notice the `async` and `await` keywords, and notice that `Task<Connection>` has turned in `Connection`.

Given that: your first code snippet looks OK.

The second one is likely to cause an issue as you're introducing another threading mechanism (namely a semaphore `AutoResetEvent`). In addition @HaspEmulator is right - if this is on the UI thread this is known to deadlock a WP app.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I still have the same problem.

The method

    `public Task<Connection> Connect(string userId, string password)
    {...}`


return `tcs.task`without waiting the execution of


    `client.ExecuteAsync<Connection>(...)`

so the result is always null

Comment: Yes that's exactly what it should do. You will only get a result if you `await` it.